Using autofit.js in vue+elementUi causes element offset
Autofit. js is a solution for adapting to large screens, but when used in conjunction with elementUI, it can cause the inner elements to shift. For example, when the item setting of el table is set to show overflow tooltip, the displayed elements will send offset when the mouse moves into this grid
I hope to achieve a normal effect without causing element displacement. Thanks

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
